# DataTemplate for ViewModel slow to display

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a simple MainWindowView

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ClassListForTeacherViewModel}">
            <local:ClassListForTeacher />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="109*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="408*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:NavigationControl Grid.Column="0"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 Width="Auto"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding MainView}"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid>
<Window>
```

and a MainWindowViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel(string name)
        : this(name, null)
    {
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel(string name, ViewModelBase mainView)
    {
        Name = name;
        MainView = mainView;
        NavigateToTeacherClassesCommand = new DelegateCommand(o => NavigateToTeacherClasses());
    }
    //
    // Properties
    //
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private ViewModelBase _MainView;
    public ViewModelBase MainView
    {
        get 
        {
            return _MainView;
        }
        private set
        {
            _MainView = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("MainView");
        }
    }

    public ICommand NavigateToTeacherClassesCommand { get; private set; }
    //
    // Functions
    //
    private void NavigateToTeacherClasses()
    {
        MainView = new ClassListForTeacherViewModel();
    }
}
```

The ClassListForTeacher view only contains a ListView control with no logic (yet). When I click the Label in the NavigationControl in the MainWindowView, the ClassListForTeacher is set on the MainView property of MainWindowView and is displayed via the DataTemplate. This is barebones program; no loading data yet. My problem is the display takes too long, maybe about a full 3 seconds. It is my first time trying out MVVM, I see this is a common technique (using DataTemplate), is this normal?

I also noticed that the ViewModel for ClassListForTeacher is called twice but I have no other code calling it. One from the NavigateToTeacherClasses function, the other I don't know. When WPF actually resolves the DataTemplate (which is a UserControl), is the constructor called again? If so, How do I prevent this?

**EDIT:**

XAML for NavigationControl

```
<UserControl...    
<StackPanel>
    <Expander Header="Grading" IsExpanded="True">
        <StackPanel Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <Label Content="My Classes">
                <Label.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding NavigateToTeacherClassesCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
                </Label.InputBindings>
            </Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

XAML for ClassListForTeacher:

```
<UserControl... 
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ListView>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: *My problem is the display takes too long, maybe about a full 3 seconds. It is my first time trying out MVVM, ... is this normal?* Do you think everyone would be using MVVM if that was normal? More importantly, we can't test your code unless you show us what's in your mysterious `DataTemplate`. Also, in your code example, how can you set your `MainView` to an instance of your `ClassListForTeacherViewModel`?

Comment: @Sheridan "Do you think everyone would be using MVVM if that was normal?" - Not everyone is using MVVM. "More importantly, we can't test your code unless you show us what's in your mysterious DataTemplate" - As I said, only a UserControl with a ListView. "Also, in your code example, how can you set your MainView to an instance of your ClassListForTeacherViewModel" - The Navigation control is a UserControl that only has a label inside with a click event that is bound to the NavigateToTeacherClassesCommand.

Comment: @g_b `"Not everyone is using MVVM"` - sorry, YES. in any of it's acceptable forms, MVVM is **the right way** to do WPF. anything else is plain **wrong**. And it's not a matter of opinion, it's a matter of code quality, reusability, proper layer separation and conciseness.

Comment: @HighCore Sorry, NO. Three out of the 5 companies I have had an interview with this couple of weeks has a WPF project that was not using MVVM. I'm inclined to take the one using MVVM that is why I am studying. Regardless of their reasons for this (I don't know why they do what they do) and regardless of opinions, the statement that everyone uses MVVM is not true.

Comment: @g_b I would really love to see how these companies deal with UI decoupling.... I too used to work on a company where they had no idea about WPF and they used it like winforms. Every time I needed to improve the UI there was a bunch of horrible coupled code that didn't allow you to do anything without breaking it all. I used to refactor entire sections of the application just to get a single feature working properly... I ended up running away from that mess